Text date to date in R: from this format: Wed, 23 Feb 2022 00:00:00
I have a dataset with dates formatted like this:
> head(dfed$`POSTED DATE`)
[1] NA                                               
[2] "Fri, 26 Jul 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)"
[3] "Thu, 4 Jul 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)" 
[4] "Tue, 5 Nov 2024 17:00:00 (Brussels local time)" 
[5] "Thu, 18 Apr 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)"
[6] "Wed, 7 Dec 2022 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)" 

I want R to read them as dates so that:
Input: "Fri, 26 Jul 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)"
Output: 26/07/2024
What I tried:

lubridate::as_datetime gave me 'All formats failed to parse. No formats found':

> as_datetime("23 Feb 2022 00:00:00")
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 


Searching through old questions didn't help


as.Date(dfed$POSTED.DATE, format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", tz="CET")

I got "NA"s as the output :(

both strptime and as.Date gave NAs

That's a locale issue. You need Sys.setlocale(locale = 'C') before using @Edward 's solution.

A convenient tool is {anytime}:
x <- c(
  "Fri, 26 Jul 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)",
  "Thu, 4 Jul 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)",
  "Tue, 5 Nov 2024 17:00:00 (Brussels local time)",
  "Thu, 18 Apr 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)",
  "Wed, 7 Dec 2022 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)"
)

anytime::anydate(x)
# [1] "2024-07-26" "2024-07-04" "2024-11-05" "2024-04-18" "2022-12-07"

It seems that you don't need to reset the locale with this function.

For the record, lubridates ymd_hms-class should also work locale-independent (note that they also have a locale argument).
Assuming this is your locale
Sys.setlocale(locale="fr_BE.UTF-8")

Sys.getlocale()
[1] "fr_BE.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/fr_BE.UTF-8/C/fr_BE.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"

while just as.Date fails
as.Date(dfed$`POSTED DATE`, format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", tz="CET")
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

using dmy_hms works (with as.Date to filter the dates)
library(lubridate)

as.Date(dmy_hms(dfed$`POSTED DATE`))
[1] NA           "2024-07-26" "2024-07-04" "2024-11-05" "2024-04-18"
[6] "2022-12-07"

Data
dfed <- read.table(te='NA
"Fri, 26 Jul 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)"
"Thu, 4 Jul 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)"
"Tue, 5 Nov 2024 17:00:00 (Brussels local time)"
"Thu, 18 Apr 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)"
"Wed, 7 Dec 2022 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)"', header=F, 
col.names="POSTED DATE", check.names=F)


dfed <- tibble(`POSTED DATE`=c(
  NA,
 "Fri, 26 Jul 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)",
 "Thu, 4 Jul 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)", 
 "Tue, 5 Nov 2024 23:59:59 (Brussels local time)", 
 "Thu, 18 Apr 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)",
 "Wed, 7 Dec 2022 00:00:01 (Brussels local time)"))

For English locales, set the system setting to "C" before parsing (in case your computer is using a different system setting).
Sys.setlocale(locale = 'C')

dfed$date <- as.Date(strptime(dfed$`POSTED DATE`, 
                     format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", tz="CET"))
dfed

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  `POSTED DATE`                                   date      
  <chr>                                           <date>    
1 NA                                              NA        
2 Fri, 26 Jul 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time) 2024-07-26
3 Thu, 4 Jul 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time)  2024-07-04
4 Tue, 5 Nov 2024 23:59:59 (Brussels local time)  2024-11-05
5 Thu, 18 Apr 2024 00:00:00 (Brussels local time) 2024-04-18
6 Wed, 7 Dec 2022 00:00:01 (Brussels local time)  2022-12-07


I think I'm getting NAs because I am working in Europe and the day abbreviations are not working correctly.
I tried to test it out with just:
tst <- "Thu"
strptime(tst, format="%a")
the output was NA.
Do you know how to fix that?

See Darren's comment above.
